# redirect one POST query to another with the same params .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core Web API app. And I have 3 API endpoints:
"/a", "/b", "/c" that accept the same parameters (Form parameters with files).

So, user do request to "/a", I check some conditions and need to redirect him to "/b" or "/c" with the same (Form data with files) parameters.

The important thing: user can also execute "/b" or "/c" separately without request to "/a". Also I need to redirect user to "/b" or "/c" inside "/a", so no response I wait for from "/a" or, in other words, response from "/a" = redirection to other endpoint.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect to a different Web API endpoint, but you can do one of those:

- User requests  "/a", and you give him a response containing the URL/URLs to "/b" or "/c".
- You have implemented a service and your controllers are logically clean. So in the controller, you only do the check which service method you should call  "/a", "/b" or "/c".

Edit3:

I highly recommend option 2, because you've mentioned that you have 3 controller actions that have the same input data. So your best way to do it is to have **only one** action and inside it call your service methods `A`, `B` or `C` depending on the input data.

Edit2:
First option pseudo-code:

```cs
[HttpPost("/a")]
public ActionResult<DefaultResponseModel> Verify(MyInputModel myModel)
{
    MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
    if(myModel.MyProperty1 == "something")
    {
         response.RedirectURL = "https://myurl/a"
    }
    else if(myModel.MyProperty1 == "other")
    {
        response.RedirectURL = "https://myurl/b"
    }
    else
    {
        response.RedirectURL = "https://myurl/c"
    }

    return Ok(respomse);
}
```

Edit:
Example of how to do the second option.

In your `Startup.cs` file in the `ConfigureServices` method you register a service like this:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

In your controller you inject it via dependency injection:

```cs
public class BusinessController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMyService businessService;

    public BusinessController(IMyService businessService)
    {
        this.businessService = businessService;
    }

    // the actions are below..
    // code here    
}
```

And then let's say in your desired action called  "/a"

```cs
[HttpPost("/a")]
public ActionResult<DefaultResponseModel> Verify(MyInputModel myModel)
{
    if(myModel.MyProperty1 == "something")
    {
         var response = this.businessService.A(myModel)
    }
    else if(myModel.MyProperty1 == "other")
    {
        var response = this.businessService.B(myModel)
    }
    else
    {
        var response = this.businessService.C(myModel)
    }
}
```

And don't forget to create the service and the implementation.

```cs
public interface IMyService
{
    ResponseModel A(MyInputModel myModel);
    ResponseModel B(MyInputModel myModel);
    ResponseModel C(MyInputModel myModel);
}
```

And the implementations of the service:

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I need to use middleware? Can you give me some examples of implementation?

Comment: Edited, if you want example for the first option, write a comment

Comment: Yes, please, give me an example of first option. I think the second doesn't match me because user can also execute "/b" or "/c" separately.

Comment: Added some more code examples and I suggest the option mentioned in Edit 3, based on the information given by you. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you very much :). But I need to redirect user to "/b" or "/c" inside "/a" action

Comment: You can't redirect someone inside a Web API project.

Comment: So then I need manually create new http request with new url, copy all data and execute it? Is there only this way? I mean this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Is there the way I can copy Request.Form data and send them in new request. Or I need to add every param separately?